# jQuery: remove select options greater than and less than

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am checking whether users degree is complete or not,

- if it is complete(i.e radio button value is true) I want to remove all the options greater than 2016 from degree completion year dropdown.
- if the degree is not completed I want to remove all the options less than 2016(but not -1).

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
$("input:radio[name=isDegreeComplete]").change(function() {

      var isDegreeCompleted = $('input:radio[name=isDegreeComplete]:checked').val();

      if (isDegreeCompleted == 'true') {
       $('#yearOfQualifyingDegree option:gt(2016)').remove();
      } 
      else 
      {
        $('#yearOfQualifyingDegree option[value<2016 && value>-1]').remove();
      }
});
```

I have tried,

```
 $('#yearOfQualifyingDegree option[value>2016]').remove();
```

But this also didn't work.
So anything is missing from it?

PS: I am using **JQuery1.11.0**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the selectors used by you are targeting required element. You need to use `.filter()` function here:

```
 $('#yearOfQualifyingDegree option').filter(function(){
   return parseInt(this.value,10) > 2016;
 }).remove();
```

Comment: and what for 2nd requirement(second bullet in question)? two filters?

Comment: change `return parseInt(this.value,10) > 2016;`  to  `return (parseInt(this.value,10) > 2016 && this.value > -1);`